# Unable to use .net framework 4 dll with BIDS 2008

Tags: .net, ssis, bids

I am trying to create an SSIS package with BIDS 2008 withsome of application dlls which i want to use in this are built in .net framework 4.

But when i am trying to refer those dlls in BIDS 2008 i am unable to add them , with no error thrown . Do any one know ho to use .net framework 4 dll with BIDS 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant, it must be 3.5.

To verify it, go inside a script task, select view -> project explorer and double click on the proprieties folder. You'll see:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that you wont be able to.  In SQL Server 2008 you are stuck with .net 3.5.